# How to make image move in a frame infinitely?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

okay so I have this right here:

html:

```
<div class="object">
        <img src="https://www.direktorenhaus.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Kabali-After-Puja-6-1-800x533.jpg" alt="pic">
      </div>
```

css:

```
.object {
  animation: MoveLeftRight 10s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

@keyframes MoveLeftRight {
  0%, 100% {
    right: 0;
  }
  50% {
    right: 300px;
  }
}
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kte1ar3p/

but instead of it moving left and right, right to left all the time, i want to to like go through... i.e when it goes from e.g right to left, it will come out again from right to left. i dont know if this makes sense as I am explaining... 
like moving a big picture into a small frame.

**EDIT:**

I got this so far, which should do with a little bit of playing around. thank you.  https://jsfiddle.net/rgsnwb79/

Comment: Maybe you could use a carousel

Comment: Are you trying to rotate the same image repeatedly?

Comment: @madeyejm yes something like that.

Comment: may i know what seems to be the reason of down-voting my question? just so i can avoid same mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Change CSS

```
.object{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.object img {
  animation: MoveLeftRight 10s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

@keyframes MoveLeftRight {
  0%, 100% {
    right: 0;
  }
  50% {
    right: -50%;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kte1ar3p/2/

Comment: thanks that is helpful. But can it be done so that the image goes fully through the frame and comes out again ? i.e moves only in one direction, so it does not come back to the opposite side.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you want to repeat the display of the image and its movement... What if you animated it like sliding the image off of itself (like a deck of cards)?

HTML

```
<div class="object">
   <img class="slide" src="https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Abstract-Patterns-For-Free.jpg" alt="pic">
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.object {
   background-image: url("https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Abstract-Patterns-For-Free.jpg");
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}

.slide {
   animation: MoveLeftRight 3s linear infinite;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

@keyframes MoveLeftRight {
   0% { left: 0; }
   50% { left: 50%; }
   100% { left: 100%; }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mittenmoon72/kte1ar3p/27/

If you're wanting a carousel, I'd just use one of the many JavaScript carousel libraries out there.